# Needleman-wunsch algorithm for two sequences of different length

Tags: python, alignment

I wrote a code to align two sequences with the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm. it is going well for two sequences the same length. When I use two sequences of different lengths, I get an error: `string index out of range`. Could anyone help me?

Thats is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
s1='ACGGAAGGACAGGGAGATAGCGCGGGGAACGAGGAAGAGGGGGGATTCCAGGGAAGGGTAAT' 
s2='TCCGTATAATAGTGCTGTACTAAGCAAATTTATAGTTCTCTAGAAAGTGCCCGC'


M=len(s1)
N=len(s2)
match=+2
gap=-1
mismatch=-2
matrix=np.zeros((N+1,M+1))

#builduing the score matrix 

# 1. putting horizontal and vertical gaps in columns and rows 
for i in range(1,N+1):
    matrix[i,0]=matrix[i-1,0]+gap
for j  in range(1,M+1):
    matrix[0,j]=matrix[j-1,0]+gap
    
# 2. putting in the score/values in the score matrix 
    
for i in range(1,N+1):
       for j in range(1,M+1):
           if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
               score1 = matrix[i-1,j-1] + match
           else:
               score1 = matrix[i-1,j-1] + mismatch
           score2 = matrix[i,j-1] + gap
           score3 = matrix[i-1,j] + gap
           matrix[i,j] = max(score1,score2,score3)
#create a traceback matrix with D=diagonal, V=vertikal, H=horizontal 
trace_mat=np.zeros((N+1,M+1),dtype=str)
for i in range(1,N+1):
    trace_mat[i,0]= 'V'
for j  in range(1,M+1):
    trace_mat[0,j]='H'
```

I would appreciate your help !!!

---

---

---

Comment: Add some string examples for clearance.

Comment: two sequences with different length 

s1='ACGGAAGGACAGGGAGATAGCGCGGGGAACGAGGAAGAGGGGGGATTCCAGGGAAGGGTAAT'

s2='TCCGTATAATAGTGCTGTACTAAGCAAATTTATAGTTCTCTAGAAAGTGCCCGC'

Comment: Please edit the question and add the string examples in the question. Also, try to clarify your desired output if possible.

Comment: ok i have put my strings in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated code is given

```
import numpy as np 
s1='ACGGAAGGACAGGGAGATAGCGCGGGGAACGAGGAAGAGGGGGGATTCCAGGGAAGGGTAAT' 
s2='TCCGTATAATAGTGCTGTACTAAGCAAATTTATAGTTCTCTAGAAAGTGCCCGC'

N=len(s1)
M=len(s2)
match=+2
gap=-1
mismatch=-2
matrix=np.zeros((N+1,M+1))

#builduing the score matrix 

# 1. putting horizontal and vertical gaps in columns and rows 
for i in range(1,N+1):
    matrix[i,0]=matrix[i-1,0]+gap
for j  in range(1,M+1):
    matrix[0,j]=matrix[0,j-1]+gap
    
# 2. putting in the score/values in the score matrix 
    
for i in range(1,N+1):
       for j in range(1,M+1):
           if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
               score1 = matrix[i-1,j-1] + match
           else:
               score1 = matrix[i-1,j-1] + mismatch
           score2 = matrix[i,j-1] + gap
           score3 = matrix[i-1,j] + gap
           matrix[i,j] = max(score1,score2,score3)
#create a traceback matrix with D=diagonal, V=vertikal, H=horizontal 
trace_mat=np.zeros((N+1,M+1),dtype=str)
for i in range(1,N+1):
    trace_mat[i,0]= 'V'
for j  in range(1,M+1):
    trace_mat[0,j]='H'
```

This should work fine if everything else you did is correct. However, I would like to point out what you did wrong:

1. The line 'M=len(s1)', 'N=len(s2)' is the one of the error that i pointed. This states that N points to the second string and M points to the first string. Therefore, the matrix is defined as `matrix[len(s2)][len(s2)]`. However, in the nested for loop, you used 'i' as the row of the matrix to define the `s1` string, and j as the column as the matrix to define string `s2`. But, this is not correct as you defined `s1` to be the row of the matrix.
2. If I state `s1` as the row of the matrix and `s2` as the column of the matrix, then the following loop is to be re-considered,

```
    for j in range(1,M+1):
        matrix[0,j]=matrix[j-1,0]+gap
```

I believe this should not be done like this, and only fixing the error as stated in point 1 solves the `string index out of range`. However, I believe this loop segment should be written as follows

```
    for j  in range(1,M+1):
        matrix[0,j]=matrix[0,j-1]+gap
```

The modification of the loop initializes the starting vertical values of the matrix. Assuming the dynamic programming approach, I believe this should be also fixed.

Comment: Thank you !! this helped me a lot. i continued my code to get the values for the traceback matrix and got the same problem. Can i show you how i continued my code  ?

Comment: How can i put the rest of my code in here ? should i edit my code below ?

Comment: thats the code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y6rjrbJ2B9/

i really appreciate your help !!